# Recyclerview issue in Android Nougat upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-recyclerview, android-7.0-nougat

My app is compilesdkversion is 23 i have to upgrade to 24 and all support libraries to 24 while upgrading the recyclerview in the app is not displaying views in a module. is there a particular change log for the issue, Suggest a solution Thanks in advance

Due to security reason i cant give my entire gradle file

```
  /* android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
       ......

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'*/
```

Comment: paste your gradle app module file

Comment: gradle details added @ND1010_

Comment: Add more info regarding your Issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the layout_height to "wrap_content" for the recyclerview items.I got the same problem,the mentioned solution resolved the issue.